# Object Slicing - Best Practices

Tags: c++

as far as I know, generally accepted practice to prevent object slicing is; deleting the copy constructor and copy assignment functions in the base class. So, in this case, don't we also indirectly delete the copy constructor and copy assignment functions for derived classes? when we write a code that calls the copy constructor or copy assignment for the derived class object, the compiler will call our deleted base class functions and will delete the copy constructor and copy assignment functions of the derived class as it fails. So, to prevent object slicing, do we indirectly delete the copy constructor and copy assignment functions of derived classes?

Comment: Every derived class is potentially someone else's base class, so making it uncopyable is not a bad thing.

Comment: Using polymorphism in C++ has several pitfalls.  Copying and assignment are two of those.  What you suggest is a good way to prevent accidental slicing.  Often, the base class will have a virtual `clone` function, so copies can be made, and have to be made explicitly.